# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Int32 get_Item(Int32)

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I am a newbie about entity framework and linq. My query is like that

```
var query = (from d in db.MYTABLE
             where d.RELID.Equals(myInts[0])
             select d.ID).Distinct();

List<int?> urunidleri = query.ToList();
```

When i execute this code, i got the error message "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Int32 get_Item(Int32)". How can i solve my problem ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You need to store your `int` in a variable, so that EntityFramework isn't trying to pull the whole array into its scope.

```
var myInt = myInts[0];

var query = (from d in db.MYTABLE
             where d.RELID.Equals(myInt)
             select d.ID).Distinct();

List<int?> urunidleri = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Generally speaking, why LINQ to Entities is trying to call get_Item(Int32) there? (question post).

Comment: Because C# is generating expression trees that involve the array.  These expressions are converted into SQL by EF, and EF doesn't know what to do with the array.

Answer (score 8):

```
var firstInt = myInts[0];
var query = (from d in db.MYTABLE
             where d.RELID.Equals(firstInt)
             select d.ID).Distinct();

List<int?> urunidleri = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Ok i see but now i am getting different error. "Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context"

Comment: @Murat, and what is the type in myInts then? Hoover your mouse over the `var` before `firstInt` to find out.

Comment: can i use foreach for IQueryable<int> object. For example
foreach(var item in query){ int x = item.Value }

Comment: @Murat, yes, if `MYTABLE.ID` is an int.

Answer (score -1):

The Linq query is ultimately transformed into an SQL query and LINQ doesn't know what to do with `Session["UserName"]` (that gets the "UserName" item).

A common way to workaround this is just to use a local variable to which you'll assign `Session["UserName"]` and that you'll use in your Linq query...

like

```
string loggedUserName = Session["LogedUsername"].ToString();
var userdetail = dc.faculties.Where(a => a.F_UserName.Equals(loggedUserName)).FirstOrDefault();
```

reference http://mvc4asp.blogspot.in/

Comment: Are you sure you are answering the right question here? The OP makes no mention of `Session` at all and this question has had an accepted answer for several years it seems (not that this means you can't add something to it but it makes it more likely to be a mistake).

Comment: The users answer is correct - it is synonymous to accepted answer, and a simplification thereof.

In essence "The Linq query is ultimately transformed into an SQL query and LINQ doesn't know what to do with "