# Linq select row where columns nth character = x

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a legacy database where i need to get all rows of a certain type. There is no column for that type to search by, but luckily there is a naming convention that has a dash for every 3rd character when its the type i want. I thought i could simply do this:

```
var sectionsList = (from sec in db.Query<Section>()
                                     where (sec.Name[2] == '-')
                                     select sec).ToList().Distinct();
```

However i get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code  Additional
>   information: Char get_Chars(Int32)

I found this which looks like the same issue:
[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Int32 get_Item(Int32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233054/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-get-itemint32)
But that case involves comparing to a local value which can be grabbed before hand. I need to iterate over the Name string during the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should use the `Substring` method:

```
var sectionsList = 
  (
    from sec in db.Query<Section>()
    where sec.Name.Substring(2,1) == "-")
    select sec
  )
  .ToList().Distinct();
```

And this should be converted into DB function like: `substring(NAME, 2, 1) = '-'`

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) Enjoy great NHibernate ;)