# linQ to entities does not recognize the method Models.Repository.Student get_Item(Int32)' method

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

getting this error on where clause. 
trying to fetch records from sql server with linQ query in entity framework.

```
 var Stud = contextSchool.Student.Where(x => x.STDNT_ID == lstStudent[i].StudentID).FirstOrDefault();
```

if i store value of list in a variable and then use in where clause, it works but not with list.

complete error:
linQ to entities does not recognize the method Models.Repository.Student get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Int32 get\_Item(Int32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233054/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-get-itemint32)

Comment: error might be the same but reason is different.

Comment: The reason is **exactly** the same. You are trying to let EF translate an array get operation into SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i also get this error on some other projects, the problem is that u cant use methods like get_Item or f.e. AddDays() in ur linq command.

So u kinda have to *play around it*.

U have to create an object (list, or whatever) before ur linq command and fill it with the data u need (per methods) and use the variable in ur linq command.