# Count total based on a foreign key value using LINQ

Tags: linq

I'm trying to do something like the following done in SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Total" 
FROM dbo.Items
WHERE CategoryID IN (SELECT CategoryID 
                     FROM Categories
                     WHERE Name = 'Beverages')
```

Any ideas how we accomplish this in `LINQ`?

***Update**

`Item` class code:

```
public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public int BrandID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Product Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product name is required")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Product Price")]        
        public decimal? ItemPrice { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
        [Display(Name = "Image URL")]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }     

    }
```

`Category` class code:

```
public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Category Name")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the primary key of Category table

Comment: CategoryId should be of type int not nullable int?

Comment: Is that what you think might be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes ,try to change it to int

Comment: Sorry bro, same error message: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'OnlineStore.Models.Category get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: I think there is something with the query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233054/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-get-itemint32

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update*
 Models

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product name is required")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Product Price")]
    public decimal? ItemPrice { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    [Display(Name = "Image URL")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Sample of data used 
[image]

You want item's where category = Beverages
You can make it from `items` end

```
var itemsCount1 = dbcontext
    .Items
    .Count(x => x.Category.Name == "Beverages");
```

You can make it from `categories` end

//if there is no Category with the name `Beverages` return 0

```
var itemsCount2 = dbcontext
    .Categories
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Beverages")?.Items?.Count() ?? 0;
```

Query Result 
[image]

Comment: CS1061 'Items' does not contain a definition for 'Categories' and no extension method 'Categories' accepting a first argument of type 'Items' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

Comment: In you Category model you should have  navigation property List<Item>

Comment: I tried the first code example you gave... i.e., from `items`.

Comment: and for the second example you gave - error message: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'OnlineStore.Models.Category get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Could you add Category , Item Model Classes

Comment: Question has been updated with the requested code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could get Count with following.

```
var results = Categories.Where(x=>x.Name.Equals("Beverages")
                    .Join(Items,
                    c=>c.CategoryID,
                    i=>i.CategoryID,
                    (c,i)=> i).Count();
```

For mock data,

```
var Categories = new List<Category>
{
    new Category{CategoryID =1, Name ="Beverages"},
    new Category{CategoryID =2, Name ="One"},
    new Category{CategoryID =3, Name ="Two"}
};

var Items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item{ItemID=3,CategoryID=4,ItemName="abc1"},
    new Item{ItemID=1,CategoryID=1,ItemName="abc2"},
    new Item{ItemID=1,CategoryID=1,ItemName="abc3"},
    new Item{ItemID=1,CategoryID=1,ItemName="abc4"},
    new Item{ItemID=1,CategoryID=1,ItemName="abc5"},
    new Item{ItemID=2,CategoryID=1,ItemName="abc6"},
    new Item{ItemID=3,CategoryID=4,ItemName="abc7"},
    new Item{ItemID=4,CategoryID=2,ItemName="abc8"},
};
```

Output : **5**

**Update**

```
var results = dbContext.Categories.Where(x=>x.Name.Equals("Beverages")
                        .Join(dbContext.Items,
                        c=>c.CategoryID,
                        i=>i.CategoryID,
                        (c,i)=> i).Count();
```

Comment: In Visual Studio, your query has an error on the keyword `.Join` saying: `The name 'Join' does not exist in the current context.'`

Comment: what is the type of object you used with Join ? say if its categories.Join , what is type of categories ? hope it is a collection ?

Comment: I believe you are using EF based on some of your comments in other answers and OP.I have updated the answer. please check

Comment: I'm sorry, your update is neither running. Same error on `.Join` keyword.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried ? especially, what data type / collection you are using